# I need help making this before and after slider work on mobile

Tags: slider, slick.js

This before and after slider I made doesn't work on mobile; itll tap to an area, but I want it to swipe like how it does on desktop. It's very choppy on mobile or when I press on the middle it wont slide at all. not sure how to fix it. I asked chatgbt but it kept making it worst. On desktop it runs perfectly and I want it toe behave the same way.

```
html
<div id="contenedor">
 <figure>
      <div id="separador"></div>
</figure>
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" id="deslizador" />
                                  </div>

css
#contenedor { 
    margin-top: -22rem !important;
    background:url(media/frontpage/before.webp) no-repeat center center;
    height: 73.5vw;
    margin: 1vw auto;
    max-height: 350px;
    max-width: 600px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 20px;
  }
  
  @media (max-width: 767px) {
    #contenedor {
      margin-top: -14rem !important;
    }
  }
  
  #contenedor figure { 
    background-image: url(media/frontpage/kitchenafter.webp);
    background-size: cover;
    font-size: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0; 
    position: relative;
    width: 100%; 
  }
  
  #separador {
    background-image: url(media/frontpage/before.webp);
    background-size: cover;
    bottom: 0;
    border-right: 5px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
    box-shadow: 10px 0 15px -13px #000;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 98.6%;
    min-width: 0.6%;
    overflow: visible;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%; 
    animation: figure 2s 1 normal ease-in-out 0.1s; 
    -webkit-animation: figure 2s 1 normal ease-in-out 0.1s; 
  }
  
  /* Barra input */
  input#deslizador {
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: none; 
    background: transparent;
    cursor: col-resize;
    height: 100vw;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    outline: none; 
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: -100vw;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  /* Barra input Mozilla */
  input#deslizador::-moz-range-track { 
    background: transparent; 
  }
  
  /* Barra input IE */
  input#deslizador::-ms-track {
    border: none; 
    background-color: transparent;
  }
   
  #separador::before {
    z-index: 999;
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: -34px;
        width: 64px;
        height: 100%;
        background: url(https://cdn.josetxu.com/img/before-after-effect-arrows.png) no-repeat scroll 0 center transparent;
        background-size: contain;
        pointer-events: auto; /* Enable pointer events on the separator */
        touch-action: pan-y; /* Allow vertical panning on touch devices */
      }

      input#deslizador::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        height: 100vw;
        width: 0.5%;
        opacity: 0;
      }
      
      input#deslizador::-moz-range-thumb {
        -moz-appearance: none;
        height: 100vw;
        width: 0.5%;
        opacity: 0;
      }
      
      input#deslizador::-ms-thumb {
        height: 100vw;
        width: 0.5%;
        opacity: 0;
      }
      

and javascript:

const slider = document.getElementById('deslizador');
const separator = document.getElementById('separador');

let isDragging = false;

function updateSlider() {
  separator.style.width = slider.value + "%";
}

function handleMouseDown() {
  isDragging = true;
}

function handleMouseUp() {
  isDragging = false;
}

function handleMouseMove(event) {
  if (isDragging) {
    const mouseX = event.clientX;
    const separatorRect = separator.getBoundingClientRect();
    const containerRect = separator.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect();

    let separatorWidth = (mouseX - containerRect.left) / containerRect.width * 100;
    separatorWidth = Math.max(0, Math.min(100, separatorWidth));

    slider.value = separatorWidth;
    separator.style.width = separatorWidth + "%";
  }
}

slider.addEventListener('input', updateSlider);
slider.addEventListener('change', updateSlider);
separator.addEventListener('mousedown', handleMouseDown);
document.addEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp);
document.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);


I tried chatgbt but it kept making it worst.
```